# Como calcular a diferença entre duas datas de uma coluna e agrupar por categoria para gerar um novo Banco de Dados no software R

Tags: r, data.frame

A seguir o exemplo do banco de dados original e do novo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Inicialmente eu gostaria de salientar que o ideal é sempre fazer perguntas com exemplos reprodutíveis. No seu caso você deveria ter fornecido o data.frame **dados** que eu acabei tendo que digitar ;-). Para você entender melhor como fazer uma pergunta com um exemplo reprodutível leia esta ajuda: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Na primeira parte eu simplesmente estou criando um data.frame igual ao que você forneceu na imagem.

```
## Criando o exemplo como um data.frame
dados <- data.frame(
  Processo = c(201701, 201701, 201702, 201702, 201702, 201703, 201703, 201704, 201704, 201704),
  Grupo = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
  Data = c('01/02/2017', '15/02/2017', '20/03/2017', '18/04/2017', '01/07/2017', '15/02/2017', '20/02/2017', '01/03/2017', NA, '05/06/2017')
)
```

Algo importante que você precisa saber sobre o R é que ao ler um conjunto de dados com datas o R inicialmente vai "entender" essas datas como strings. Você precisará converter estas strings para o formato de datas do R tal que você possa fazer operações de soma e subtração com datas:

```
## Convertendo para data
dados$Data <- as.Date(dados$Data, format = '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Veja que eu forneci um argumento **format** que mostra ao R como os dias, os meses e o ano estão representados. Eu usei o Y maiúsculo pois o ano é apresentado com 4 dígitos.

Por fim basta usar o dplyr para agrupar e depois calcular a diferença entre a maior e a menor data. Veja que eu usei a opção na.rm = T para remover o NA.

```
## Carregando o pacote dplyr
library(dplyr)

## Agrupando e calculando a diferença entre as datas com o dplyr
dados %>%
  group_by(Processo, Grupo) %>%
  arrange(desc(Data)) %>%
  summarise(Total_Dias = max(Data, na.rm = T) - min(Data, na.rm = T))
```

O resultado é exatamente a tabela final que você postou:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Processo [?]
  Processo Grupo Total_Dias
     <dbl> <fct> <time>    
1  201701. A     14        
2  201702. B     103       
3  201703. C     5         
4  201704. A     96
```